# Swift 3, how to parse first and show it on next TableViewController

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I am really new to developing iOS apps. So I also apologize in advance if my coding is not close to being optimal or good written...

I am trying to create fairly simple app only for showing retrieving and showing data, but I hit a bump which I am trying to solve it for past few days, but I need help...
So the whole functionality of the app is like this: when opened(displying viewcontroller with textfield and button), user should enter username and push button. After button is pushed app should then do 2 things in next order:

1. combine certain URL address with entered username, retrieve data
   (what kind of data, depends on given username - I gave few examples
   on the bottom of that post) and pass them to next
   tableviewcontroller
2. display tableviewcontroller and show parsed data.

But, this does not happen, what I noticed is, that my app opens new tableviewconotrller first, and after tableviewcontroller is open, it parses data, which causes that my table has no data (but I can see that data has been parsed, using print())

I am using Swift 3.

ViewController with textfield and button for "login":

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
   var zavodi = [[String]]()
   @IBOutlet weak var uporabnik: UITextField!

@IBAction func vstop(_ sender: Any) {

  self.parse { (completed) in
     if (completed){
        let zavodiView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "zavodiController") as! ZavodiController
        zavodiView.niz = self.uporabnik.text!
        zavodiView.zavodi = self.zavodi
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(zavodiView, animated: true)

        }
     }
  }


   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      self.title="Vstop"
   }


     func parse( completion: @escaping (_ completed: Bool)-> () ){
      let uporabnikIme = uporabnik.text!
      //parsing
      let shramba = UserDefaults.standard

      let zavodiUrl = "https://oaza.rrc.si/eZaporiMobi/kapStSta/read?pUporabniskoIme="+uporabnikIme;
      var zavodiRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: zavodiUrl)!)
      zavodiRequest.httpMethod = "GET"

      let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
      let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

      let task = session.dataTask(with: zavodiRequest) { (data, response, error) in
         if (error != nil) {
            print("Error")
         }
         else {
            var zavodiTemp = [Zavod]()
            do {
               let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! NSArray
               //print(fetchedData)

               zavodiTemp.removeAll()

               for najdenZavod in fetchedData {

                  let vsakZavod = najdenZavod as! [String : Any]

                  let zavodId = vsakZavod["zaiId"] as! Int
                  let naziv = vsakZavod["kratekNaziv"] as! String
                  let ureditev = vsakZavod["ureditev"] as! Int
                  let zasedenost = vsakZavod["zasedenost"] as! String
                  let kapaciteta = vsakZavod["kapaciteta"] as! Int
                  let stStanje = vsakZavod["stStanje"] as! Int
                  let naBegu = vsakZavod["naBegu"] as! Int
                  let prekinitev = vsakZavod["prekinitev"] as! Int


                  zavodiTemp.append(Zavod(zavodId: zavodId, naziv: naziv, ureditev: ureditev, zasedenost: zasedenost,kapaciteta: kapaciteta, stStanje: stStanje, naBegu: naBegu, prekinitev: prekinitev))
               }
               zavodiTemp = zavodiTemp.sorted(by: {$0.ureditev < $1.ureditev})

               self.zavodi.removeAll()
               for e in zavodiTemp {
                  var temp = [String]()
                  temp.append(String(e.zavodId))    //0
                  temp.append(e.naziv)              //1
                  temp.append(String(e.ureditev))   //2
                  temp.append(e.zasedenost)         //3
                  temp.append(String(e.kapaciteta)) //4
                  temp.append(String(e.stStanje))   //5
                  temp.append(String(e.naBegu))     //6
                  temp.append(String(e.prekinitev)) //7
                  self.zavodi.append(temp)
               }

               let steviloZavodov = self.zavodi.count

               shramba.set(self.zavodi, forKey:"zavodi")
               shramba.set(steviloZavodov, forKey:"steviloZavodov")

               var s = [[String]]()
               s = shramba.array(forKey: "zavodi") as! [[String]]
               for e in s{
                  print(e[2]+" "+e[1])
               }
            }
            catch {
               print()
            }
          }
         }
         task.resume()
  completion(true)

}

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   }


   class Zavod {
      var zavodId : Int
      var naziv : String
      var ureditev : Int
      var zasedenost : String
      var kapaciteta : Int
      var stStanje : Int
      var naBegu : Int
      var prekinitev : Int

      init(zavodId : Int, naziv : String, ureditev : Int, zasedenost : String, kapaciteta : Int, stStanje : Int, naBegu : Int, prekinitev : Int) {
         self.zavodId = zavodId
         self.naziv = naziv
         self.ureditev = ureditev
         self.zasedenost = zasedenost
         self.kapaciteta = kapaciteta
         self.stStanje = stStanje
         self.naBegu = naBegu
         self.prekinitev = prekinitev
      }

   }

}
```

TableViewController where should parsed data be displayed:
import UIKit

```
class ZavodiController: UITableViewController {
   var niz = ""
   var zavodi = [[String]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      print(niz)
      }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      print("število zavodov"+String(self.zavodi.count))
        return self.zavodi.count
    }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "zavodCelica", for: indexPath) as! ZavodCelica

      cell.nazivZavoda.text = self.zavodi[indexPath.row][1]
      cell.kapaciteta.text = self.zavodi[indexPath.row][4]
      cell.zasedenost.text = self.zavodi[indexPath.row][3]
      cell.stStanje.text = self.zavodi[indexPath.row][5]
      cell.naBegu.text = self.zavodi[indexPath.row][6]
      cell.prekinitev.text = self.zavodi[indexPath.row][7]



      return cell
   }


}
```

I also tried to use UserDefaults, but it just seems that tableviewcontroller just simply gets loaded before actual parsing is done.

For usernames, you can use:
-"manj", returns 1 record
-"mref", returns 3 records
-"mmli", returns 14 records

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: i didn't read the code but have your tried reloading the table after your data is parsed ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will take a look at that and try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be a lot of ways to achieve this. Reloading the table is also a fix. But to be very accurate with the data your should wait for the function completion before moving to the next screen. Look at the code

```
func parse()( completion: @escaping (_ completed: Bool)-> () ){


// parse logic goes in here
// after the processing finishes return true like following

  completion(true) // you can also have logic to return failures.

}
```

This will be called like

```
self.parse { (completed) in

  if (completed){
       let zavodiView = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "zavodiController") as! ZavodiController
       zavodiView.niz = uporabnik.text!
       zavodiView.zavodi = self.zavodi
       navigationController?.pushViewController(zavodiView, animated: true)
  }

}
```

Comment: I tried that (I edit source code in question, so that you can see) by making those changes to ViewController...but it still works with delay, transition between controllers gets executed before all the data are parsed ...

Comment: I have found the issue in your code.

completion(true) should go after you have completed the task inside its body.
You have placed it after  task.resume()

move that after the for loop -> for e in s{ }

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nqmjfxzn0jf9izx/Screen%20Shot%202018-02-23%20at%201.06.24%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works, I really do appreciate your help. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Afetr appending data to the table array add this

```
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableview.reloadData()
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand how to use that in that case where I parse data in first controller and show the data in second... or should I parse them in the same controller where those data or shown?

Comment: you can parse them out if this class but provide a completion and inside it reload the table